# Cannot generate a consistant token ASP.NET C# server-side Oauth2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, access-token

I am having troubles trying to autogenerate a token that all client-side users can use. Am using Oauth 2.0.

I can perfectly generate a token localhost, using Account controller `/api/Account/Register`, but when I publish the web api I cannot access with that token, and I also can't generate the token like I did localhost.

Is there any way to generate a token server-side like I do localhost?, it should be consistent in the way that when I republish the app that token should still be the same.

I am using Postman to test it. When I call `/api/Account/Register` with this json:

```
{
  "Email": "da@a.com",
  "Password": "sample striAng 21|",
  "ConfirmPassword": "sample striAng 21|"
}
```

it returns me an error in like this:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

I am copying exactly what I did localhost, but on server doesn't work.

Comment: Token generated on a localhost and on the server are always going to be different, generete your token calling to that API, use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (_or any other tool_) to test it out

Comment: Hi, I have tried but it doesnt work.

I call de Account controller from postman to create a account and get the token but i get an error.

Comment: Well and what's the error? You need to add those details to your question, and usually you cal to `/Token` to get the token when using API, you need to show use what are you doing

Comment: The thing is that the error message i get says nothing.

I recibe a json like this: 

{
    "Message": "An error has occurred."
}

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly set-up Database, or published the correct files and dll's? Usually that message is of an internal error

Comment: If I remove the  [Authorize] tag to test it works properly. So yes  I think is all correctly set up

Comment: Why are you using `[Authorize]` on register? It's not gonna work! you're trying to register yourself, you're not logged in, that's why it doesn't work

Comment: I ment that I remove `[Authorized]` from my own controllers in order to test them, not Account controller.

Also remember that Register method has a tag `[AllowAnonymous]`.

Comment: Ok, do this set on your web.config `<system.web><customErrors mode="Off"/></system.web>` this way you will see all the 500 errors and see what says

Comment: I got something intresting : 

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)".

Comment: What i don't understand here is why I have a sql problem, being that Account controller never uses any database?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're connecting to a SQL Express Database on your local machine, but in most of the cases Servers don't use SQL Express (Nor have the same credentials when login to it) you MUST set up your web.config and sql connection.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database
>   Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly
>   installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)"

On your Web.config change/comment out your current connectionStrings and replace it with the one of your server

```
 <connectionStrings>       
    <add name="YourDataBaseContextName" connectionString="Data Source=TheConnection;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;User Id=TheUserOfDatabase;Password=YourHopeNotSoEasyPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

> What i don't understand here is why I have a sql problem, being that Account controller never uses any database?

They do use it, after all you must save the register data on somewhere, right?

More specifically this lines register and save to database the model that you send:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };    
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Comment: Thank you very much William :) It worked!! 

Gracias!

Comment: @PabloSalazar Remeber to accpet the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like 500 internal server error. 
Any other endpoint is working all everything dosn't work?

You shold check connection string on server, and check if db exist and have proper tables.

Make sure that any envirement specyfic setting has valid value.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer.

Database exists, connection string is working properly, becouse if I remove the [Authorized] tag (so I can use the webapi with no authentication), it works perfect.